# how to make action from included graph?

Tags: android-navigation, android-navigation-graph

I can make action from nested graph to any destination, but apprently I can't make action from included other file.

i thought included graph and nested graph is almost same.
how can I make action from included graph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a global action in the main navigation graph
Like:

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/x">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/x"
        android:name="x"/>

    <include app:graph="@navigation/x" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/firstFragment"
        android:name="x"/>

    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_global_to_firstFragment"
        app:destination="@id/firstFragment" />

</navigation>
```

And then call it with the id:

```
navController.navigate(R.id.action_global_to_firstFragment)
```

The navController must be the defined in the ActivityContainer, if it generate a destination error, maybe you aren't using the main navController